# How to find, the shortest distance from $O(0,0)$ to the line passing through $A(2,3)$ and $B(3,5)$.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I tried to solve this problem by distance formula and I get $\sqrt5$ . But this answer is incorrect.

Comment: If you write here the solution that you came up with, we could check it.

Comment: $\sqrt{5}$ is the distance between the two given points though; perhaps you calculated that distance? If you show us your work, it's easier to help you.

Comment: How did you find your answer? Is the answer $\frac1{\sqrt5}$? Maybe you have a minor mistake only.

Comment: I calculated distance between two given points.your answer is right $1/√5$ . How did you get it? Is there formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
d=\frac{|\vec{OA}\times\vec{OB}|}{|\vec{AB}|}=\frac{|(x_A-x_O)(y_B-y_O)-(x_B-x_O)(y_A-y_O)|}{\sqrt{(x_B-x_A)^2+(y_B-y_A)^2}}\\
=\frac{|2\cdot5-3\cdot3|}{\sqrt{(3-2)^2+(2-1)^2}}=\frac1{\sqrt5}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The equation of $AB$ it's $$2x-y-1=0,$$ which gives that the distance it's:
$$\frac{|2\cdot0-0-1|}{\sqrt{2^2+(-1)^2}}.$$
Can you end it now?

Answer (score 0):

The line through $(2,3)$ and $(3,5)$ is $y=2x-1$, or equivalently $2x-y-1=0$

Thus the distance of $(0,0)$ from this line is

$$\frac{|2 \cdot 0 + (-1) \cdot 0 + (-1)|}{\sqrt{2^2+(-1)^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{5} $$

Comment: I used this formula $d$= $√(x2 − x1)^2 + (y2 − y1)^2$

Comment: @LondonJack this is the formula for the distance between two points. The distance from a point to a line is the distance from that point to its orthogonal projection on the line. Hence if the line is $l:ax+by+c=0$ and the point is $P=(x_P,y_P)$, then $d(P,l)=\frac{|ax_P+by_P+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$